# catch the parameter post from view on same controller spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a code in php language using codeigniter framework. I need to translate it into spring framework, but i little confuse to translate like send parameter into controller with the paramater like :

```
$tipe   = $this->input->post("tipe_lst");
```

because in spring we using:

```
@RequestParam("tipe_lst") String tipe_lst
```

how to catch the parameter on the same controller?, because the parameter is not always have a value, it can also null parameter, so if i use @requestparam, the result can be an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `required = false` in @RequestParam annotation.
Like this;)

```
@RequestParam("tipe_lst", required = false) String tipe_lst
```